# Wire over 1ft does not work with sensors SRF02

Tags: sensors

Im using an SRf02 ultrasonic sensor, and I need to make the wires long to elevate the sensor. They turn on and blink and are able to transmit a signal, yet they are not able to receive a signal. What is the error?

[image]

Comment: Which interface are you using - UART or I2C?

Comment: im using i2c as the interface

Comment: I thought you might be. Are you using the internal pullups of the Arduino IO pins or have you added external pullup resistors?

Comment: internal, i havent added any resistors

Comment: Again, I suspected as much.

Answer (score 1):

Using the internal pullup resistors for I2C is not recommended.  Arduino are very wrong in providing those as the default option and basically "hiding" the fact that I2C needs decent pullup resistors from you.

The internal pullup resistors, because they are so weak (i.e., a high resistance, typically > 50KΩ), do not pull the clock and data lines up adequately, and as such are only suitable for very short connections (in the order of a few inches).  Anything longer and the induced noise and inductance and capacitance of the wires will corrupt the I2C waveform.

I2C requires pullup resistors in the range of 2.2KΩ to 4.7KΩ.  As you can see that is more than 10x the pullup strength of the internal resistors.

For off-board connections (i.e., wires) you want the lower end of that range.  So add a 2.2KΩ resistor between SCL and +5V and another between SDA and +5V and you should find it works much better.

Comment: so what do you mean, add the resistor between SDL and V+, i cant just place it in between SDL on arduino and the TX pin of the sensor?

Comment: I mean exactly what I say. Connect a 2.2k resistor with one end connected to the SCL pin on the Arduino and the other end connected to +5V on the arduino. The same with the SDA pin.

Comment: i uploaded a picture in the original post, is this what you mean?

Comment: I don't know, it's too small to make out.

Comment: i put a better picture

Comment: It's confusing to work out what goes where in that picture, but I think you have it right, yes. It's not exactly a hard concept, there's only two ends to a resistor and I have told you the two places they connect to.

Comment: yeah i get what the circuit is supposed to look like, it didnt work btw